# Pass parameters from the root saga to the action dispatched

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-saga, react-boilerplate

I have a simple saga. The Idea is to listen the action `REQUESTS_OWNERSHIP_EDIT` to be dispatched from the store and run submit `submitOwnerships(ownerships)` that is supposed to submit the ownership params to the server. 
I'm confused about how to get the `ownerships` value in the function dispatched from the saga.

Here it is my code:

```
// saga.js

import request from 'utils/request';

import { select, call, put, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { editOwnerships } from './actions';
import { REQUESTS_OWNERSHIP_EDIT } from './constants';

export function* submitOwnerships(ownerships) {
  // I would like to have here ownerships equals to the parameter passed to my action. 
  const requestURL = 'http://localhost:3001/';
  try {
    const art = yield call(request, requestURL, { method: 'POST', body: ownerships });
    yield put(....);
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(....);
  }
}

export default function* ownershipEdit() {
  yield takeLatest(REQUESTS_OWNERSHIP_EDIT, submitOwnerships);
}


// actions.js

export function editOwnerships(ownerships) {
  return {
    type: REQUESTS_OWNERSHIP_EDIT,
    ownerships,
  };
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3):

The `submitOwnereship` saga gets the `action` (the result of `editOwnerships` function) and you can use an object destructuring to receive `ownerships`:

```
export function* submitOwnerships({ ownerships }) {
  ...
}
```